# Discerning between a number 'x' as a Natural or Real number

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology, set-theory, numbers

The usual way of teaching is to explain the numbers that are element of the reals and naturals as being the same, this was a perfectly valid way of understanding for me, why do some consider '2' as an element of the reals, different to '2' as an element of the natural numbers due to their definition in set theory and why do we do this?

As an inexperienced student, is this worth taking note of? Is there any well defined consensus on whether an element x is the same as either a real of natural number? Is it better to simply consider '2' as the same abstract object.

We just refer to the number as one thing, 'the number 2' is there many things that can be referred to like this?

[Here's an example of such an idea](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21378/what-is-the-number-2)

Comment: The definition of *number* in a philosphical sense (the essence of number) is a complex and yet unsolved issue. Mathematics has with different theories: arithmetic, set theory that define how numbers work.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA for most purposes, I shall think of a single abstract entity then.

Comment: To first *really* understand and visualize the real number line, you need to address this simple paradox: it's a mundane fact from the *denseness* of the rational numbers in the real numbers that between every 2 distinct irrational numbers there's a rational number and symmetrically between every 2 distinct rational numbers there's an irrational number. Then how is it possible from our mundane intuition that Cantor rightly proved there must be much much more irrational numbers than all the rational numbers in terms of cardinality?...

Comment: The standard view is that natural numbers are a set of their own, and there is an isomorphic copy of them inside the reals. In elementary mathematics this would be just pedantry, but in mathematical logic people want to study simpler (arithmetic) and more complex (real analysis) systems independently and not rely on properties of the latter when dealing with the former. One can also think of 2 as a single platonic entity that both arithmetic and analysis capture, but then it is distinct from its formal reflections in both.

Comment: @Conifold So then, Outside of logic contexts there is one 'number 2' that we perform operations and use to represent quantities (in real life, counting etc), but we can consider each version of '2' in each set as being slightly different? So when we talk about an expression x+2 in 99% of contexts x is a 'number' not specifically either representation but in correct situations we can specify two different objects we call '2'? Say I have the set defined as {1,2,3} In this case how do we differ between '2' as an element of the naturals, or the reals? How can it be the same set?

Comment: I.e how can a set containing the natural numbers {1,2,3} be the same set as the set containing the real numbers {1,2,3}?

Comment: In most cases what is called "working mathematicians" take the "naive" stance that they are working with objects that have platonic identities untethered from any particular formal system. 2 as a natural and 2 as a real are not distinguished naively, and in formal contexts do not appear in the same expression, they belong to different systems. If you are working in formal set theory like ZFC then it has its own copy of naturals ([realized as sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers)) which sits inside its copy of reals, so {1,2,3} will be unambiguous.

Comment: Modern competent mathematicians who are aware of the [Benacerraf's identification problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benacerraf%27s_identification_problem) do notice the faulty naive Platonism conception and more towards some kind of structualism such as reflected in the widespread use of category theory: *arguing that the Platonic attempt to identify the "true" reduction of natural numbers to pure sets, as revealing the intrinsic properties of these abstract mathematical objects, is impossible....the relation of set theory to natural numbers cannot have an ontologically Platonic nature.*

Comment: "how can a set containing the natural numbers {1,2,3} be the same set as the set containing the real numbers {1,2,3}?" Agreed: in the context of set theory, the two numbers 2 are different sets: thus, they are different objects. But they behave the same way, e.g. 1+1=2 both for naturals and reals. Thus, we identify them from the math point of view, where "structural" properties matter. Answers received to the [same post in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519784/do-we-draw-a-distincton-between-a-number-as-an-element-of-the-reals-and-an-elem) are a good starting point.

Comment: @Conifold so for most working mathematicians it's the same object and it defines the same set (for their purposes)? and hence we can write it so. Take a typical mathematical expression, in this case, we use this perfect '2' that is both a natural and real? But in formalized systems we would define which object it is?

Comment: In Peano arithmetic, for example, there are no reals, so 2 will be a natural number only. In ZFC, {∅,{∅}} represents 2 as both a natural and a real, reflecting the naive approach. One context where you would want to distinguish them is meta-theory, where you consider several formal systems and talk about relations between their models. For example, you may want to say that there is a map from a model of arithmetic that embeds it into a model of reals and 2-real is the image of 2-natural under this map. Once people say that they may further say that they "identify" naturals with their images.

Answer (score 1):

In a strict sense they are not the same, the naturals **N** and the reals **R**, by the usual construction, are different things. But, it happens that there is a natural embedding *f*: **N**---> **R** such that the set **N** (the naturals) and *f*(**N**) (a subset of **R**) are *naturally isomorphic* ("equivalent in a broad sense") and, thus,in a certain sense it is indifferent to speak of the properties of 2 in **N** or of the properties of *f*(2) in **R**.

Answer (score 0):

Kronecker said:

> God created the integers; all else is the work of man.

This is why we call the integers the natural numbers because they seem to be a work of nature rather than than an invention of man. But if one follows this thought, then one see's that this cannot possibly be correct. If God created the integers then he also created all other numbers - the reals, the imaginaries, the Lie algebras, the finite groups and so on.  All of them are as natural as the integers. That we do not think so is merely that we are unfamiliar with them.

This position, whether you believe in God or not, is called mathematical Platonism. In fact, its such a truncated version of Platonism that its serious mistake to think this is what Platonism is about. But we are stuck with the name. In this notion numbers have ideal existences that are only accessible to the inner sense of the intellect. Here, numbets are unique and there are no copies. Although this notion to contemporary ears sounds bizarre and few mathematicians would give it credence, it is more or less how most mathematicians naively go about working with them.

The other main option is nominalism. Here the number three is understood, for example, to be about the collection of ALL three objects. This option became popular with the advent of set theory which is a theory of collections. Still, even this approach can be suspect since the unrestricted use of ALL as Russell pointed out leads to inconsistencies. Also, personally speaking, I think it unwieldy and not at all how I think of numbers and I suspect, pretty much everybody else. Its rather like describing a book as a collection of pages, which even if true, is only partially true, and doesn't get to the idea of a book as a thing in itself.

If you ascribe real essences to numbers then its of course wrong to think of 2 as an integer as different from 2 as a real. That people do so may seem from this point of view completely wrongheaded. Nevertheless, one can argue that they do so only as a manner of speaking and are actually focusing on different properties of the same thing because those are the properties that they are interested in - either in the pure mathematics sense where numbers are their own end - or practically because what they are modelling requires only those properties.